# I want to know about Google NDB data store keys

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am new to GAE. I started working on NDB data store service. But the Parent key structure of it really confusing me. I also watched some tutorials on YouTube but they just explain its documentation.

I also followed the documentation but still it is not clear to me. It is the link which i explored.

[Google App Engine NDB Data Store Service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. see [how to write a good stackoverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) this question does not fit here because is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NDB datastore is a distributed system. Absolute data consistency is very hard for distributed systems in general. By default NDB is eventually consistent. This means that by default:

- If you add a record it may not appear immediately in a query
- You cannot do transactions across multiple records by default

If you have more strict requirements you can define groups of entities by giving them the same parent key and specifying it in queries. You are then able to get consistent behaviour within these groups.

It is often better to not to use parent keys at all since they come with a heavy performance penalty. Most of the time apps do not need parent keys.

Quote from [Entities, Properties, and Keys](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/entities#Python_Transactions_and_entity_groups)

> There is a write throughput limit of about **one transaction per second** within a single entity group. This limitation exists because Datastore performs masterless, synchronous replication of each entity group over a wide geographic area to provide high reliability and fault tolerance.

Comment: Thank you. I will not use parent keys :)